# csom context credential security

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks, csom

I have a task schedular in which i am connceting to sharepoint site and fetching some data using csom script c# and after processing sending the mails to users.

i am creating the context by passing user credential which are stored in app.config file as below code.

```
  ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            context.RequestTimeout = int.MaxValue;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(siteUserName, siteUserPassword, siteDomain);
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web, w => w.Title);
            context.Credentials = credentials;
            return context;
```

how we can store these credentials other than config file for security?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the credentials in a database, and retrieve them when you want to create the ClientContext.

Comment: Yes we can but again it is not secure to store client context credentials in database. on task scheduler creation i used that client context and it should run under that privilege.i worked for me.

Comment: Storing credentials in app.config won't give you more security than storing in database. Unless your database is really not safe. Check this topic with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28412209/824644

Answer (score 0):

You can store the credentials in Windows Credentials Manager, then use this [library](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/Utilities/CredentialManager.cs) to get the ICredentials object

```
ICredentials credential = CredentialManager.GetSharePointOnlineCredential("site url");
```

By doing this, you let Windows handles the encryption and storing of username and password.